# Are those with access to moderator tools allowed to moderate their own posts?

Tags: support, flagging

As per the title, are mods (and non-mods with semi-mod powers due to high privileges) notified and/or allowed to moderate their own posts which others have flagged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only actual ♦ moderators can see a summary of all flags and act on these (i.e. dismiss as helpful or decline them).

Users with [10k privileges](https://superuser.com/privileges/moderator-tools) see a subset of flags and may act on them by flagging the posts another time or disputing the flags. They cannot, however, act on these flags in any other way. As a consequence, "normal" users with 10k reputation cannot see flags on their own posts and can therefore not act on them.

Since moderators see all flags, they also see flags on their own posts. This means they could also act on these flags, although I guess many moderators would leave flags on their own posts to be handled by another moderator for the sake of fairness and transparency.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. (Also, I would suppose most mods here would think it's bad form to moderate their own posts.) I briefly considered the idea that the name of the mod who responded to a flag should be displayed as well, but I think that's just going to cause needless resentment so it's not a good idea at all.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid that'd do more harm than good. If there's a flag decision you don't understand, you're free to flag again, ask on Meta, come to chat, et cetera. It's always easier to settle things then, and we should be focusing on the content, not the moderator who handled it.

Comment: "we should be focusing on the content, not the moderator who handled it" - Yes, absolutely, which is why I knew it was a bad idea. Ideally speaking, all mods should behave in a similar and more importantly, consistent manner so that to users it does not matter who specifically did what.